# Ruby group array of hashes by numeric key

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I got an array of hashes like this one:

```
[{1=>6}, {1=>5}, {4=>1}]
```

I try to group by the keys.

So the solution with named keys was like: `group_by { |h| h['keyName'] }`.

How can I get the following array with short Lambda expressions or with group_by:

```
[{1=>[5, 6], 4=>[1]}]
```

**EDIT** - To explain what I am trying to achieve:
I got a database to allocate pupils to courses.
Each pupil is able to vote each year for a course.

The votes look like this:

```
Vote(id: integer, first: integer, second: integer, active: boolean,
     student_id: integer, course_id: integer, year_id: integer,
     created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Now I would like to allocate the pupils automatically to a course, if the course is **not overstaffed**. To find out how many pupils voted for each course I first tried this:

```
Year.get_active_year.votes.order(:first).map(&:first).group_by(&:itself)
```

the result looks like this:

```
{1=>[1, 1], 4=>[4]}
```

Now I am able to use the .each function:

```
Year.get_active_year.votes.order(:first).map(&:first).group_by(&:itself).each do |_key, value|
  if Year.get_active_year.courses.where(number: _key).first.max_visitor >= value.count

  end
end
```

*each course got an explicit number and the pupils just use the course number to vote.*

But if I do all this, I lose the information which pupil voted for that course, so I tried to keep the information like this:

```
Year.get_active_year.votes.order(:first).map{|c| {c.first=> c.student_id}}
```

Comment: This sounds like a [classic XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... what are you trying to achieve? what did you try? and how on earth did you find yourself with an array of Hashes to being with?

Comment: Why do you prefer `[{1=>[5, 6]}, {4=>[1]}]` over `{1=>[5, 6], 4=>[1]}`? That's so unusual and probably bad that two out of the three answers so far didn't even notice they're not doing what you asked for (and neither did the people who upvoted them).

Comment: Oh wait, correction, *all three* answers get it "wrong".

Comment: What is a "named key" and an "unnamed key"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Injecting into a default hash:

```
arr = [{1=>6}, {1=>5}, {4=>1}]
arr.inject(Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=[]}){|h, e| h[e.first[0]] << e.first[1]; h}

# => {1=>[6, 5], 4=>[1]}
```

Or, as suggested in the comments:

```
arr.each.with_object(Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}){|e, h| h[e.first[0]] << e.first[1]}

# => {1=>[6, 5], 4=>[1]}
```

Answer (score 2):

```ruby
def group_values(arr)
  arr.reduce(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) do |memo, h|
    h.each { |k, v| memo[k] << v }
    memo
  end
end

xs = [{1=>6}, {1=>5}, {4=>1}]
group_values(xs) # => {1=>[6, 5], 4=>[1]}
```

Note that this solution also works when the hashes contain multiple entries:

```ruby
ys = [{1=>6, 4=>2}, {1=>5}, {4=>1}]
group_values(ys) # => {1=>[6, 5], 4=>[2, 1]}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [{1=>6}, {1=>5}, {4=>1}]

arr.flat_map(&:to_a).
    group_by(&:first).
    transform_values { |arr| arr.transpose.last }
  #=> {1=>[6, 5], 4=>[1]}
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = arr.flat_map(&:to_a)
  #=> [[1, 6], [1, 5], [4, 1]]
b = a.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {1=>[[1, 6], [1, 5]], 4=>[[4, 1]]}
b.transform_values { |arr| arr.transpose.last }
  #=> {1=>[6, 5], 4=>[1]}
```

Note that

```
b.transform_values { |arr| arr.transpose }
  #=> {1=>[[1, 1], [6, 5]], 4=>[[4], [1]]}
```

and `arr.flat_map(&:to_a)` can be replaced with `arr.map(&:flatten)`.

Another way:

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  k,v = g.flatten
  h.update(k=>[v]) { |_,o,n| o+n }  
end
  #=> {1=>[6, 5], 4=>[1]}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs the block `{ |_,o,n| o+n }` to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. The block variable `_` is the common key (represented by an underscore to signal that it is not used in the block calculations). The variables  `o` and `n` are respectively the values of the common key in the two hashes being merged.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this using `#group_by` could be to group by the first key of each hash, then `#map` over the result to return the corresponding values:

```
arr = [{1=>6}, {1=>5}, {4=>1}]
arr.group_by {|h| h.keys.first}.map {|k, v| {k => v.map {|h| h.values.first}}}

# => [{1=>[6, 5], 4=>[1]}]
```

Hope this helps!